# SQL -- create column in SELECT to test equality

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

In SQL Server, I'm dealing with these columns:

tblSchedule

---

ID
StaffID
StartTime
EndTime

I want to include a boolean field in my result set that indicates whether StartTime and EndTime are equal.  Something analogous to this:

```
SELECT StaffID, StartTime, EndTime, (StartTime = EndTime) AS AreEqual
FROM tblSchedule Where StaffID = xxx
```

But I'm not sure of the actual syntax for an operation like that.

Comment: Your solution is standard, should work.

Comment: That solution was giving me an error in SQL Server Mangement Studio.   The CASE..ELSE  statement, as inelegant as it looks, worked like a charm.

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: true that it conforms to the SQL-99 Standard i.e. the `BOOLEAN` data type. However, SQL Server has not implemented that part of the Standard. Arguably SQL Server should implement this but the truth is, it hasn't yet got a boolean data type.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
SELECT  StaffID
        , StartTime
        , EndTime
        , Case
          When StartTime = EndTime Then 1
          else  0
        End as AreEqual
FROM    tblSchedule
Where   StaffID = xxx
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using a `CASE WHEN` in your `SELECT` statement; something like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN StartTime = EndTime THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS AreEqual
FROM MyTable
```